# Decompress tar.gz file in Go

Tags: go, io, compression

I want to extract `tar.gz` file and store the contents in the same directory. I got below method which does the job but I wanted to see if there is any way to improve below code if there is any efficient way?

```
func ExtractTarGz(gzipStream io.Reader, logger log.Logger) (err error) {
    uncompressedStream, err := gzip.NewReader(gzipStream)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(uncompressedStream)

    for true {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Next() failed: %s", err.Error())
        }

        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir:
            if err := os.Mkdir(header.Name, 0755); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Mkdir() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case tar.TypeReg:
            outFile, err := os.Create(header.Name)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Create() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
            defer outFile.Close()
            if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, tarReader); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Copy() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
        default:
            return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: uknown type: %s in %s", header.Typeflag, header.Name)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

- I am seeing possible resource leak on `defer outFile.Close()` line. Not sure how should I fix that.
- Is the way I am returning error from this method looks good here or something that can be improved here?

I will be running this code in production so if there are any other improvements that can be done in the above code then I would like to make those before I run it in prod so opting for code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```golang
func ExtractTarGz(gzipStream io.Reader) error {
    uncompressedStream, err := gzip.NewReader(gzipStream)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(uncompressedStream)
    var header *tar.Header
    for header, err = tarReader.Next(); err == nil; header, err = tarReader.Next() {
        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir:
            if err := os.Mkdir(header.Name, 0755); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Mkdir() failed: %w", err)
            }
        case tar.TypeReg:
            outFile, err := os.Create(header.Name)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Create() failed: %w", err)
            }

            if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, tarReader); err != nil {
                // outFile.Close error omitted as Copy error is more interesting at this point
                outFile.Close()
                return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Copy() failed: %w", err)
            }
            if err := outFile.Close(); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Close() failed: %w", err)
            }
        default:
            return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: uknown type: %b in %s", header.Typeflag, header.Name)
        }
    }
    if err != io.EOF {
        return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz: Next() failed: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

So few things changed:

1. We're iterating over reader till there is an error (we're doing 1 error check less on each iteration) with the same functionality as before (we're checking the io.EOF at the end now).
2. I've changed returning the errors with error wrapping "%w", with that you can later on use errors.Is() if you would need that in any case.
3. I've added the error check for closing the file - a common thing to overlook.
4. Removed `defer` for the Close function. In the case of many files, you would end up with a lot of files opened till all of them are copied. Better just to close it after copy. The functionality will be changed as in the edge case of failing on closing the file, the decompressing will change.
5. Changed error formating of type flag - linter is shouting that it is not string so "%s" should not be used.
6. Removed logger from function arguments - unused variable.

Regarding the returning errors. I would not use the prefix of the function name, as you know in the code that you're using certain function. I would remove it here and put it in the in the place where you invoke this function.
So

```golang
if err := ExtractTarGz(gzipStream); err != nil {
     return fmt.Errorf("ExtractTarGz failed: %w", err)
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in this code - the loop condition should be `err == nil`, not `err != nil`. I can't edit the code because the edit has to be >6 characters, but just letting everyone know :)

Comment: Fixed, good catch! :)